# Pass string from page URL to HTML <P> tag

Tags: javascript, html, dom

Noob JS question: Is it possible to customize a paragraph tag on a webpage with a name by adding the name to the URL?

So, for example, if the page has to say **Hello XYZ**, can the URL be **website.com/msg=XYZ**

The msg=XYZ can be changed to anything string without requiring a separate webpage for each string.

Thanks
Vila

Comment: yes, but be careful since users can pass a script into your html or deface a webpage... https://www.owasp.org/index.php/HTML_Injection

Comment: This approach is subject to [XSS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting)

Comment: @YeldarKurmangaliyev thank you for the headsup

Comment: @shanimal will be careful thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access the current URL with

```
var url = document.URL;
// => website.com/msg=XYZ
```

Then you could get the last guy with split

```
var texts = url.split("/");
// => ["website.com","msg=XYZ"];
```

Then create a paragraph tag with the text you want

```
var p = document.createTextNode(texts[1]);
document.body.appendChild(p);
```

Comment: You may also use `texts[1].split("=")[1]` to remove `msg=` part.

Comment: @jonah thanks will try this out! Any way to overcome the XSS vulnerability?

Comment: Found this plugin called PagerJS that achieves the same effect: http://pagerjs.com/demo/#!/model/params/search?product=tv&price=200 but has jquery and knockoutJS dependencies. I wonder if this approach is immune to XSS ?

Comment: @RDMD Never mind, just reviewed this a little. `createTextNode` is **XSS safe**. It creates **text** node and escapes any unsafe HTML symbols.